# Having trouble with using Spring JDBC libraries in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I have recently downloaded the latest version of the spring framework: spring-framework-4.0.0.M1-dist.zip(sha1), but I only wanted the JDBC libraries that came with it, which consisted of 3 jars, as far as I could tell. I have tried to include these jars in my project in Eclipse by configuring my build path for them. Whenever I do this, and try to extend a class from one of these libraries, it says it is unrecognized, and as a solution, to import the appropriate package: okay, fine. So I import it, and it still throws me an error saying:
"The type org.springframework.dao.support.DaoSupport cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files" whenever I hover over the class being extended.

I would provide a screenshot, but I need to have at least a 10 reputation, and I am new to this website, so I apologize.

I have tried using the default unzipping tool which is already on Windows 7, I have used 7Zip, and have tried to include external jars without creating a folder in Eclipse to place the jars in, and I have tried to make a folder and include them, and have also tried deleting and re-downloading the entire spring framework. Still the same error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In which folder you had included your jars?

Comment: I created a folder called lib, in which the next directory up was the project itself

Comment: put libraries in lib folder under web-inf/lib folder or configure it in build path.

Comment: im actually running java se 6, i sense this could be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

When I face this problem usually, I go with a clean build in eclipse if the project is configured correctly. In order to use any jar files in general you right click on the project 
Build Path->Configure Build Path and make sure that you see those jars in libraries tab, if not add them; having them in a 'lib' directory serves no purpose as they must be included in the .classpath file of the project regardless the directory.

Comment: Right, I understand that a new directory folder really serves no purpose, I was just trying  a different approach as opposed to adding external jars. And I do see the needed jars in the library tab, and have seen the class I extended within one of those jars.

Comment: Make sure there is no dependency between those jars as far as I remember you can't have the Spring JDBC jars only, the spring framework jars need to go in as well.

Comment: hmm okay, so include the spring framework in my project? I don't know what dependencies exist, and there are a lot of files

Answer (score 0):

Hey I found solution to this problem that after adding some jar package (DapSupport dependent some other classes) like [org.springframework.transaction-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar] compiled without errors.
If there is fault, it is necessary to see whether there are other jar package has not been imported....thanks